# RuntimeError and IOError when using multiprocessing in a PyQt script

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module in a `for` loop inside a PyQt class.
Unfortunately, this script give me a lot of errors. Here is the script which just displays a "Run" button and starts a process in a loop which prints a value.

```
import multiprocessing
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class SurfViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Button_Run = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Button_Run)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.Button_Run.clicked.connect(self.Runclick)

    def Runclick(self):
        for i in range(5):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker,args=(i,))
            p.start()

    def mp_worker(self,a):
        print('a:' + str(a))
        return

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong here since the below code is working well:

```
import multiprocessing

class maclass():
    def __init__(self,):
        for i in range(5):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker , args=(i,))
            p.start()

    def mp_worker(self,a):
        print('a:' +str(a))
        return

def main():
    maclass()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The only difference being that the multiprocess is done in `Button_Run.clicked. event`.

The error I get is (from the first script):

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
>       self = load(from_parent)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
>      return Unpickler(file).load()
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
>      dispatchkey
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 1221, in load_build
>      setstate = getattr(inst, "**setstate**", None)
>
> RuntimeError: super-class **init**() of type QPushButton was never called

But I also get other error when I try to use multiprocess in my bigger application, for instance:

> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\pickle.py", line 492, in save_string
>
> self.write(BINSTRING + pack(" i", n) + obj)
>
> IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Maybe this one can by correlated to the first error.

Anyone already seen a solution to that issue?

**Edit:** I tried to use @ImportanceOfBeingErnest example below. So Here's the new code:

```
import multiprocessing
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class maclass():
    def __init__(self,):
        pass

    def start(self, n):
        lfp=[]
        for i in range(n):
            recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker , args=(i,send_end))
            p.start()
            send_end.close()
            lfp.append(recv_end.recv())
            recv_end.close()
            print(i, lfp)
         #p.join()

    def mp_worker(self,a,send_end):
        print('a:' +str(a))
        send_end.send(a)
        return

class SurfViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Button_Run = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Button_Run)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.worker = maclass()
        self.Button_Run.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        for k in range(5):
            self.worker.start(4)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this case, I would like to receive a result from the worker with `recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe()`. This code works fine in the sense that I get the correct result. Unfortunately, it seems that I lose the multiprocessing ability. I'm clearly doing something wrong with the pipe, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Your worker function is a method of a Qt window. This means every new process would to have that (or a copy of) that window. Windows can not be pickeled and handed over to the new window. You have to separate your worker from the UI.

Comment: Thanks for you respond. It is the answer I did not want... ;)
because I would like to use the worker as a part of the class to modify some members of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my issue.
Here is the code that perform the multiprocessing and also handle the result return from the multi-thread worker:

```
import multiprocessing
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class maclass():

    def __init__(self,):
        pass
    @classmethod
    def start(self, n):
        lfp=[]
        r=[]
        for i in range(n):
            # queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
            recv_end, send_end = multiprocessing.Pipe()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker , args=(i,send_end))
            p.start()
            r.append(recv_end)
        for recv_end in r:
            lfp.append(recv_end.recv() )
            print(i, lfp) 
    @classmethod
    def mp_worker(self,a,send_end):
        print('a:' +str(a))
        send_end.send(a)
        return


class SurfViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Button_Run = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Button_Run)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.worker = maclass()
        self.Button_Run.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        for k in range(5):
            self.worker.start(20)



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A big thanks to the people who helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep the worker separated from the UI. The following works fine. If you want to modify variables in `maclass` you can still do it from the outside.

```
import multiprocessing
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class maclass():

    def __init__(self,):
        pass

    def start(self):
        for i in range(5):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.mp_worker , args=(i,))
            p.start()

    def mp_worker(self,a):
        print('a:' +str(a))
        return


class SurfViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SurfViewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Button_Run = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
        self.mainHBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.Button_Run)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX_param_scene)

        self.worker = maclass()
        self.Button_Run.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        self.worker.start()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SurfViewer(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I will try that and I come back to share if that works.
Thank you.